How to index for json array in Mysql 8.0.37?
I have a table with JSON data in MySQL and I'm trying to optimize queries on this data using indexes. Here’s how I’ve set up my table and inserted some data:
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
`data` JSON DEFAULT NULL);


INSERT INTO `table1` (`data`)
VALUES (
    '{"metaData": {
        "tag": ["info"],
        "attributes": [
            {"key": "Server", "value": "1"},
            {"key": "Level", "value": 53},
            {"key": "power", "value": 10}
        ]
    }}'
);

I attempted to add an index as follows:
ALTER TABLE idx1
  ADD INDEX cancel_no_idx ((
    CAST(data->>"$.metaData.attributes[*].key" as CHAR(255) ARRAY)
  )) USING BTREE;

However, when I run a query to check if the index is being used:
Is there a way to create an index that can be used for the following query?
SELECT *
FROM `table1`
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(
    data->'$.metaData.attributes',
    '{"key": "Server", "value": "1"}',
    '$'
);
    
    +----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
    | id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
    +----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | table1 | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
    +----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+

https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=435880da-a637-4cc0-958b-63d5a2602381

You index only key attribute but search by the whole $.metaData.attributes.

May be simpler to create a normalised data structure out of your json and search in that...

In current versions of MySQL, multi-valued indexes only index arrays of scalars.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued:

Creating multi-valued Indexes
You can create a multi-valued index in a CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, or
CREATE INDEX statement. This requires using CAST(... AS ... ARRAY) in
the index definition, which casts same-typed scalar values in a JSON
array to an SQL data type array. A virtual column is then generated
transparently with the values in the SQL data type array; finally, a
functional index (also referred to as a virtual index) is created on
the virtual column. It is the functional index defined on the virtual
column of values from the SQL data type array that forms the
multi-valued index.

(bold emphasis mine, to focus on the parts where it talks about scalar values)
This means you can't use a multi-valued index to search for arbitrary JSON documents, as you are trying to do.
You can only use the multi-valued index to search for a single scalar value of the same type, or an array of scalar values of the same type.
In this case, you would be better off not storing data in JSON format at all. Store data in normal rows and columns, and use conventional indexes.
It's much easier to write a query this way, and make a compound index for the respective columns of the table1_attributes table:
SELECT *
FROM `table1` AS t JOIN `table1_attributes` AS a USING (table1_id)
WHERE a.`key` = 'Server' AND a.value = '1';

Using JSON in a relational database frequently makes it much harder to write and optimize queries. I generally recommend to avoid storing data in JSON if you need to search or sort that data. Basically, if you try to reference the JSON column in the WHERE clause (or any other clause besides the select-list), then you're already in trouble.
